# Что лучше цикл с условием или без него?

Tags: c++

Обычно тело цикла выглядит как-то так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { /* code */ }
```

Как новичок, вижу следующий плюс: проще *читать*/*строить*/*изменять* логику тела цикла.
Но я для себя обнаружил следующий вариант:

```
for (int i = n; i--;) { /* code */ }
```

Где вместо условия мы пишем декремент. И как мне кажется, все плюсы пропадают, но при этом у нас нет условия, остается только шаг и не нужно вычислять булевое значение.

Я слабо знаком с Assembly и тем более теорией компиляторов. Поэтому мне кажется, что лучше использовать второй вариант. Справедливо ли это утверждение, если да, то на каких платформах?

Comment: Эти циклы выполняют разную работу. Как их можно сравнивать?

Comment: @Croessmah Я допускаю, что есть случаи, когда первый вариант нельзя перестроить во второй.

Comment: компилятор, видя первый вариант, быстро догадается, что нужно делать. В втором - не факт, может сказать, ок Джонатан, попробую собрать как есть. А вообще, к примеру, clang даже цикл для нахождения суммы ряда может на формулу готовую заменить. и будет одно сложение и одноумножение

Comment: `start: mov cx, n; loop start`

Comment: если вместо условия  пишется выражение, то это выражение и является условием.

Comment: В любом исполнении цикл задом наперёд будет быстрее если граница **n** - не меняется. Проверка индекса на нуль быстрее будет.

Comment: Не думайте об оптимизации в описании цикла. Нужно писать так, чтобы это было максимально читаемо. Компилятор оптимизирует всё сам.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Условие во втором варианте никуда не делось. Будет производится неявное приведение результата `i--` к булевому типу путем сравнения с нулем: `for (int i = n; 0 != (i--);)`. Лучше это или хуже - это будет сильно зависеть от содержимого цикла.